# Multiple Tab Chrome Extension Issue

Tags: google-chrome-extension, content-script

I've created a basic extension that searches Google if the URL/HTML content fulfill certain requirements. It works for the most part, but fails miserably when there are multiple instances of the extension. For example, if I load tab A and then tab B, but click on the page action for tab A, I will be directed to a search of tab B's content.

I don't know how to silo the script to each tab, so that clicking tab A's page action will always result in a search for tab A stuff. How can that be done? I'd appreciate your suggestions!

background.js

```
title = "";
luckySearchURL = "http://www.google.com/search?btnI=I%27m+Feeling+Lucky&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&q=";

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        if (request.title != "") {
            title = request.title;
            sendResponse({confirm: "WE GOT IT."});
        }
    });

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, change, tab) {
    if (change.status === "complete" && title !== "") {
        chrome.pageAction.show(tabId);
    }
});

chrome.pageAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.create({url: luckySearchURL + title})
})
```

contentscript.js

```
function getSearchContent() {
    url = document.URL;
    if (url.indexOf("example.com/") > -1)
        return "example";
}

if (window === top) {
    content = getSearchContent();
    if (content !== null) {
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({title: content}, function(response) {
        console.log(response.confirm); })
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like store the `title` with its associated `tabId`, that way when you click on the `pageAction` it uses the correct title. The changes would be just these:

**background.js**

```js
title= [];

[...]

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request,sender,sendResponse){
  if (request.title != "") {
    title.push({tabId:sender.tab.id, title:request.title});
    sendResponse({confirm: "WE GOT IT."});
  }
});

[...]

chrome.pageAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  title.forEach(function(v,i,a){
    if(v.tabId == tab.id){
      chrome.tabs.create({url: luckySearchURL + v.title});

      // Here I am going to remove it from the array because otherwise the 
      // array would grow without bounds, but it would be better to remove
      // it when the tab is closed so that you can use the pageAction more
      // than once.
      a.splice(i,1);
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're facing this issue because of `window === top`. So your `title` variable gets its value from the last opened tab. So if B is opened after A, `title` gets its value from B. Try this: Detect Tab Id which called the script, fetch the url of *that* tab, which then becomes your `title` variable. As below:

```
chrome.pageAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.query({active:true},function(tabs){
           //this function gets tabs details of the active tab, the tab that clicked the pageAction

           var urltab = tabs[0].url;
           //get the url of the tab that called this script - in your case, tab A or B.

           chrome.tabs.create({url: urltab + title});
    });
});
```